# How did Hermione become the Minister for Magic?

Tags: harry-potter, character-motivation, the-cursed-child, hermione-granger

I don't like *The Cursed Child* at all, but since JKR has confirmed that it's canon, can someone tell me how Hermione ends up as Minister for Magic? It's quite evident that she probably has the educational qualifications and skills required but she isn't really shown to have great leadership or diplomacy skills, which, even as a Minister for Magic, is something extremely necessary to have.

Moreover, in Chapter 7 of *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* ("The Will of Albus Dumbledore"), when Scrimgeour suggests that she should pursue a career in Magical Law, she retorts that she wouldn't because she "wants to do some good to the world".

So, after two books of hating the way the Ministry actually functions, why did she want to take charge? This seems pretty out of character to me.

Comment: Maybe she took charge to make changes and bring some good to the world

Comment: If you don't like the way something is, you have two choices: do nothing or try to change it. Which do you think sounds **more** like Hermione? (Hint: it's not "do nothing".)

Comment: JKR only developed the Cursed Child with Jack Thorne, and it is indeed considered as a canon only. This is not the only plot hole in this story, even the time-turners. So the answer would be, it is up to you if you want to believe this story or not. Many potterheads chose to ignore this, though.

Comment: @ur_Auror these aren't "plot holes", if you're going to throw the term around, actually teach yourself of the definition. (this goes for 90% of the internet)

Comment: What? Why? These are plot holes. It is said in the series that if you go back on time too much, you could die.

Comment: @ur_Auror It's also said that there's no way to survive Avada Kedavra, but the entire series of books is about a kid who did exactly that. There are consequences for using a time-turner to travel back long periods of time, but I don't think it's unbelievable that they managed to find a magical way to minimise - or even eliminate - those. Or they just got lucky in Cursed Child, just like Harry got lucky time and time again in the first seven books.

Comment: I would agree on what you said about Avada Kedavra, but that's because JKR wrote that herself. Whereas in Cursed Child, Jack Thorne's the one who did.

Comment: @ur_Auror (1) Not every statement is factually correct. It's not far-fetched for someone to say "(A) is impossible" when they really mean "There is no evidence of (A) having ever happened" (this is the basis for **many** stories where the hero does something amazing). (2) "unmentioned" does not equal "plot hole". A plot hole is a **contradiction**, not just an omission. (3) "if you go back on time **too much**" This is very vague. What constitutes "too much"? Without using hard numbers, there is no way to measure if someone is actually travelling "too much".

Comment: "As our investigations currently stand, the longest period that may be relived without the possibility of serious harm to the traveller or to time itself is around five hours. We have been able to encase single Hour-Reversal Charms, which are unstable and benefit from containment, in small, enchanted hour-glasses that may be worn around a witch or wizard’s neck and revolved according to the number of hours the user wishes to relive." and that is from Pottermore.

Comment: "As our investigations currently stand", there is only supposition, whoever went further back (was it Delphi?) could've been an outlier. Similar to how people shouldn't really survive falls from 18000 feet, yet people have. Or she jumped 5 hours at a time.

Comment: The entire purpose of investigations is to uncover things that are not currently known. Note that that same article includes a story about someone who traveled more than 500 years into the past

Comment: @ur_Auror: Pottermore is putting efforts in investigating that? Awesome science! Or is it just a quote of someone from pottermore? Then it would be interesting who said it? If it is a character.... Do you also consider it a plot hole when a story's super villain claims to be invincible just before he gets defeated? I mean I can clearly show you a quote where he said he is invincible, and still he got defeated, has to be a plot hole!

Comment: @Valorum I apologise for not having accepted the answer sooner. It indeed is comprehensive, with a lot of reliable references. I was merely waiting for any other answer that might offer a different viewpoint, but on rereading yours, I'd say it seems just about right. Thanks =)

Comment: Cheers for the accept

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Hermione's post-Hogwarts career is detailed in an interview with JKR. In short, she decided to work at the Ministry in order to further her SPEW campaign. Over time she became known as a powerful and progressive voice for liberal modern wizarding

> **JKR:** *Harry and Ron utterly revolutionized the Auror Department at the
> Ministry of Magic... Hermione began her post-Hogwarts career at the
> Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures where
> she was instrumental in greatly improving life for house-elves and
> their ilk. She then moved (despite her jibe to Scrimgeour) to the
> Department of Magical Law Enforcement where she was a progressive
> voice who ensured the eradication of oppressive, pro-pureblood laws.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Bloomsbury Live Chat with JKR](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/source/interviews/blc/)</sup></sub>

In the Quidditch World Cup (2014) article written by Rita Skeeter and published on Pottemore, we learn that she was already tipped as a future Minister for Magic, described as a "*ruthless careerist*".

> *Hermione Granger, of course, was always the femme fatale of the group.
> Press reports of the time revealed that as a teenager she toyed with
> the young Potter’s affections before being seduced away by the
> muscular Viktor Krum, finally settling for Potter’s faithful sidekick.
> **After a meteoric rise to Deputy Head of the Department of Magical Law
> Enforcement, she is now tipped to go even higher within the Ministry,**
> and is also mother to son, Hugo, and daughter, Rose. Does Hermione
> Granger prove that a witch really can have it all? (No – look at her
> hair.)*
>
> <sub><sup>[Quidditch World Cup 2014 - The Compiled Articles *via Reddit*.](https://www.reddit.com/r/PottermoreWritings/comments/4ql0kh/2014_quidditch_world_cup_the_compiled_articles/)</sup></sub>

and

> *Almost all of the Weasley family are supporting Brazil. Certainly
> nobody can have expected Ronald to cheer on his wife's ex-boyfriend.
> Both his children – Rose, who appears to have inherited her father's
> unfortunate hair, and Hugo, who has his mother's bushy locks – are
> decked out in green, but Hermione Granger is not wearing anything to
> indicate which team she is supporting. Does she secretly hope to see
> Krum take the trophy at last? Or **is this the kind of diplomatic
> neutrality one might expect of a ruthless careerist whose long-term
> ambition is undoubtedly to be Minister for Magic?***
>
> <sub><sup>[Quidditch World Cup 2014 - The Compiled Articles *via Reddit*.](https://www.reddit.com/r/PottermoreWritings/comments/4ql0kh/2014_quidditch_world_cup_the_compiled_articles/)</sup></sub>

Given her connections to Harry Potter and the (now victorious) Order of the Phoenix, it would seem that her personal charisma, coupled with her deep connections to the great and powerful meant that she was able to rise to the position of Minister for Magic with relative ease.

Comment: Let's not forget that she is repeatedly implied to be one of the most gifted witches in a generation, charisma and connections aside.

Comment: "her personal charisma" - ***WHAT*** charisma? She's horrible! No wonder she hasn't got any friends!

Comment: She’s actually rather more successful at motivating and organizing people than one would initially imagine. For example, it was Hermione who got the idea of the DA off the ground in the first place, and managed to convince more than 20 people to come out and listen to Harry. 

SPEW failed not because of her leadership skills, but because she was campaigning against ingrained practices in wizarding society (not to mention constantly irritating the house-elves themselves while doing it).

Comment: Yeah, let's remember it's mostly just _Ron_ who complains about Hermione, and that's because he likes her so much.

Comment: I would love to smack Rita Skeeter.

Comment: @MissMonicaE - You're supposed to think that :-)

Comment: @Valorum - Still, that seems a short-sighted response to be provoking out of people when you are a housefly animagus.

Comment: @MissMonicaE i get that JKR got harassed by paparazzi s lot, but i dont like her all-negative portrayal. [It's not fair when lot of journalists in the world risk their lives.](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/09/06/indian-journalist-gunned-outside-home-bangalore/)

Comment: @T.E.D. none of the journalists i'd met had any sense of self-preservation

Comment: @MissMonicaE in conjunction of what Valorum said, if you don't want to smack Rita Skeeter something isn't right with you :-P. On another note, some of the Ladies and Gents of Mos have been asking for you, any interest in joining our free area of conversing? [Valorum's profile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum) has more details, we'd love you to join :)

Comment: I think she's repeatedly shown to have more emotional intelligence than both Harry and Ron (an admittedly low bar), albeit that it comes up largely in the context of helping the boys understand girls.

Comment: @witchy Well, we shouldn't take one cliché depiction to represent all reporters, just as we shouldn't conflate one cliché politician with all of them. The politicians arguably get the benefit that there are multiple different ones appearing in the story, but she generally uses some clichés for fun characters (but still manages to give them enough authenticity to not feel like hollow cardboard dummies). But, if at all, I've always read it as a jibe against tabloid reporters of the Rita-sort, not all of them. Same goes for politicians and middle class families ;)

Comment: @FrankHopkins oh i absolutely loved the evil Slytherin journalist with her mercantile approach, i just wish there was also a wiz Hemingway fighting voldy.

Comment: @witchy well, not fully fleshed out as an adult and not exactly a writing journalist, but Lee Jordan at least shows some positive reporting attitude (though he also needs to learn to be less biased I guess when choosing which fun facts to cite^^)